# System.Text.Json: Deserialize JSON is failing (.net core 6 + Ubuntu + Wine)

Tags: c#, json, ubuntu, .net-core, wine

We have .net framework based application which connects with backend using REST API. When we run this application using Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 it works perfectly well. Our requirement is that we need to covert this .net framework based application to .net core 6 first and then run using Wine on Ubuntu.
After this transformation, when we run the application and try to Deserialize JSON returned from REST API, it is failing with following error

```
Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)
0204:fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L".NET Runtime"): stub
0204:fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (CAFE4242,0x0001,0x0000,0x000003ff,00000000,0x0001,0x00000000,003AD66C,00000000): stub
0204:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"Application: APP.exe\nCoreCLR Version: 6.0.522.21309\n.NET Version: 6.0.5\nDescription: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 0144D5A8 (01320000) with exit code 80131506.\n"
0204:fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (CAFE4242) stub
wine: Call from 7BC29F80 to unimplemented function KERNEL32.dll.RaiseFailFastException, aborting
Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
```

Strange thing is that this behavior is intermittant. Sometimes Deserialization succeeds as well.
We have seen same behavior with Newtonsoft.Json APIs as well

Code line is as follows:

```
value = (T)System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(T));
```

We are using Wine 7 version.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: have you ensured that the returned JSON is _always_ valid?

Comment: Are you able to capture / log the JSON when the exception is thrown to try replaying it in a test application to reproduce any error?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes, we tried storing JSON in a file and then passing it to Deserialize function. However with this, behavior is very intermittent. Sometimes it fails and sometimes succeed.